# Is there an alternate word for "decontenting"?

Tags: synonyms

I am discussing the introduction of basic economy flight class and how it provides a cheaper option through "decontenting", removing the customer's access to the overhead bin. However, I am not sure if "decontenting" is a proper word to use in a report. It is in no way a formal report, but I still wish to use proper diction.

Comment: Hi, @Skipher, welcome to ELU. Ideally, questions should reflect some initial research and/or investigation into an answer on the part of the questioner. Please indicate what research has been done, if any, regarding the word in question.

Comment: I'm not finding a "real" definition for "decontent".  It is apparently used in the auto sales biz to mean "removing features" from an auto line, to cut costs, but I'm not sure if that's the meaning you intend.

Comment: "Decontenting" has been widely used for the sales of software and video games where companies remove relevant contents and redistributing it as a separate package for additional cost.

Comment: Well, if it's not formal, why not just say it directly? -- *screwing the consumer*

Comment: A professor will be reading it, so I wish to word it more elegantly.

Comment: You could use any of the following terms to describe the service offered: _stripped back, pared back, simplifed_ or even _spartan_. _No frills_ is sometimes used but the overhead baggage compartment hardly seems like a 'frill' to me so I think you need a stronger term. Personally I don't think _decontenting_ is a good choice, not only is it an advertising buzzword that many people have not encountered I struggle to see the facilities offered by an airline as 'content' in the way that software functionality is 'content'.

Comment: Among other things, your statement does not explain how this "decontenting" reduces costs.

Comment: Getting things as 'bare' as customers can 'bear' without them getting disgruntled. Baloo's song about 'the bare/bear necessities of life'; hard to feel 'decontented' without feeling 'discontented', though. To me, 'decontent' sounds much too much like 'discontent' to be received positively, to have positive connotations, which does not make it very marketable!

Comment: to 'decontent' = to 'rock-bottom'? to 'hard-seat'?

Answer (score 1):

> Decontenting

In this context, maybe:

> reducing services

Keep it simple.

Comment: Taylor… Frederick Winslow? Just kidding!

Comment: A compliment, I think